# How in CakePHP update rows with limit and order by conditions

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to update rows with "order by" and "limit" conditions.
How can i using **Model::updateAll()** method update rows with "order by" and "limit" ? 
**EDIT:**  
When i try to execute this query in Model->query() method: "UPDATE table_name SET status = 2 WHERE type = 1 AND status = 1 ORDER BY id asc limit 10", i got error "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' at line 1". But when i execute this query in mysql console client, all ok.

Comment: How about first prepare list of elements to update and then put list of "id" into updateAll condition?

Comment: Actually, i would like to solve this problem by one query, if it possible of course

Comment: In my opinion that would be simplest idea for Your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP 2.x does not support `LIMIT` and `GROUP` parameters for `Model::updateAll()`.

You can use `Model::query()` to run the custom SQL that you need. Model callbacks will not be triggered however.

I would suggest that if you need to updateAll with GROUP and LIMIT that you think again about how best to provide the functionality you need.

It's not a good idea to have to update all of the rows in your database... what if you had 75 million rows? It could take hours to run and complete. Even if you don't ever expect to have 75 million rows, it's still probably not a good solution.

It's hard to provide a better example since you haven't described *why* you want to updateAll.

Comment: When i try to execute this query in Model->query() method: "UPDATE table_name SET status = 2 WHERE type = 1 AND status = 1 ORDER BY id asc limit 10", i got error "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' at line 1". But wheh i execute this query in mysql console client, all ok.